# MySQL - Conditional MIN MAX to return distinct record

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, distinct, mysql-5.7

I have a database dump from [the geonames website for Great Britain](http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/). It consists of approx 60000 records.
example data is as follows:

```
id       |     name    |   admin1   |   admin2   |  admin3  |  feature_class  |  feature_code
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2652355  |   Cornwall  |   ENG      |     C6     |          |      A          |    ADM2
11609029 |   Cornwall  |   ENG      |            |          |      L          |    RGN
6269131  |   England   |   ENG      |            |          |      A          |    ADM1
```

The first record with feature code ADM2 means it is administrative level 2
The secord record with feature code RGN means it is a region.

I want to search for records by place names to build an autocomplete feature. 
Where records have the same name and if one of those records is a region i.e. has feature_code RGN then I want to return only that 
record otherwise I want to return the record which matches that name that has the lowest id.

I have tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
   SELECT IF(t0.feature_code = 'RGN', MAX(t0.id), MIN(t0.id)) as id
       , CONCAT_WS(', ', t0.name,
                  IF(t3.name != t0.name, t3.name, NULL),
                  IF(t2.name != t0.name, t2.name, NULL),
                  IF(t1.name != t0.name, t1.name, NULL)) AS name
     FROM locations t0
  LEFT JOIN locations t1 ON t1.admin1 = t0.admin1 AND t1.feature_code = 'ADM1'
  LEFT JOIN locations t2 ON t2.admin2 = t0.admin2 AND t2.feature_code = 'ADM2'
  LEFT JOIN locations t3 ON t3.admin3 = t0.admin3 AND t3.feature_code = 'ADM3'
  WHERE 
      (t0.feature_class IN ('P', 'A') OR (t0.feature_class = 'L' AND t0.feature_code = 'RGN' ) )
      AND t0.name like 'Cornwall%' 
  GROUP BY CONCAT_WS(', ', t0.name,
                     IF(t3.name != t0.name, t3.name, NULL),
                     IF(t2.name != t0.name, t2.name, NULL),
                     IF(t1.name != t0.name, t1.name, NULL))
  ORDER BY t0.name
```

It returns the incorrect record:

```
id      | name
---------------------------
2652355 | Cornwall, England
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that *conditional aggregation* should do the trick. You can filter records by `name`, then apply the logic within aggregate functions. If a record exists with `feature_code = 'RGN'` then you want to select it, else you would pick the minimum `id` in matching record.

```
SELECT IFNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN feature_code = 'RGN' THEN id END), MIN(id)) id_found
FROM mytable
WHERE name = @name;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/x7Gkk6a3JEBevtVzj9s8cR/0)** when searching for `'Cornwall'`:

```
| id_found |
| -------- |
| 11609029 |
```

NB : if you want the whole matching record, one solution is to simply `JOIN` the above resultset with the original table:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM mytable t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT IFNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN feature_code = 'RGN' THEN id END), MIN(id)) id_found
    FROM mytable
    WHERE name = @name
) x ON x.id_found = t.id;
```

**[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/x7Gkk6a3JEBevtVzj9s8cR/1)**:

```
| id       | name     | admin1 | admin2 | admin3 | feature_class | feature_code |
| -------- | -------- | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------------- | ------------ |
| 11609029 | Cornwall | ENG    |        |        | L             | RGN          |
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select l.*
from locations l
where l.id = (select l2.id
              from locations l2
              where l2.name = l.name
              order by (feature_code = 'RGN') desc,  -- put regions first
                       id asc
             );
```

In MySQL 8+, you can also use `row_number()`:

```
select l.*
from (select l.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name 
                                order by (feature_code = 'RGN') desc, id
                               ) as seqnum
      from locations l
     ) l
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: I've updated my post but I don't understand how I can apply your first query to search by name?

Comment: @adam78 . . . You would just add `and <whatever other conditions you want` to the `where` clause.

Comment: sorry I don't understand it. Could you update your answer using the SQL I've posted so that I can understand whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

one approach could be exists and union all

```
select t1.* from location t1
where exists ( select 1 from location t2 where t2.name=t1.name and t2.feature_code='RGN'
             )
 and t1.feature_code='RGN'
union all

select t1.* from location t1
where not exists ( select 1 from location t2 where t2.name=t1.name and 
                t2.feature_code='RGN'
                  )
  and t1.id=(select min(id) from location t2 where t2.name=t1.name)
```

Comment: Note there could be multiple rows with the same name but different feature_codes so I would need the query to be dynamic.

Comment: @adam78 my answer will cover your describe problem statement so if you have any other's pattern of data i think you need to describe that in the description

Comment: I want to search for records by place names - I'm trying to build an autocomplete lookup. Where names are the same I want to ensure the lookup returns distinct record but using the criteria as described.

Comment: @adam78 it will work for any place names and you can search just by adding  condition AND name LIKE 'Cornwall%'

Comment: I've updated my post with the SQL I'm using to better describe what I'm trying to achieve. Are you able to update your answer by using the SQL in my post please.

Comment: Try using a `case` statement to return a column you can use for determining the value for feature_code - when =region then 1 else 0 and then you can use `exists` / `not exists` to include or exclude rows based upon the existence of 1 and 0

Comment: If you want actual SQL code you are going to need to provide more data - you have mentioned four levels in you query but have only provided two in your sample data. Provifde a more complete example. I am interested for example to understand how the ADM3 layer applies in your example.