# MySQL - Grouping using MIN not working as expected

Tags: sql, group-by, mysql-5.7

I have the following union query where i'm setting a dummy row number:

```
SELECT @row_num:=2 as row_num, id, name, admin1, admin3, admin4
  FROM locations
 WHERE feature_class IN ('P', 'A')
   AND name LIKE 'cornwall%'
UNION ALL      
SELECT @row_num:=1 as row_num, id, name, admin1, admin3, admin4
 FROM locations
WHERE feature_class = 'L' AND feature_code = 'RGN'
  AND name LIKE 'cornwall%'
```

This returns the following results:

```
row_num   |   id       |     name    |   admin1   |   admin3   |  admin4  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
   2      |   2652355  |   Cornwall  |   ENG      |            |          
   1      |   11609029 |   Cornwall  |   ENG      |            |
```

Now when I add this query as a subquery and use MIN to select row with the lowest row_num I get incorrect results:

```
 SELECT MIN(t0.row_num), 
   t0.id,
   t0.name, 
   t4.name AS town_admin4,
   t3.name AS county_admin3, 
   t1.name AS admin1
  FROM (
           SELECT @row_num:=2 as row_num, id, name, admin1, admin3, admin4
            FROM locations
           WHERE feature_class IN ('P', 'A')
             AND name LIKE 'cornwall%'
           UNION ALL       
           SELECT @row_num:=1 as row_num , id, name, admin1, admin3, admin4
            FROM locations
           WHERE feature_class = 'L' AND feature_code = 'RGN'
             AND name LIKE 'cornwall%'
      ) t0
  LEFT JOIN locations t1 ON t1.admin1 = t0.admin1 AND t1.feature_code = 'ADM1'
  LEFT JOIN locations t3 ON t3.admin3 = t0.admin3 AND t3.feature_code = 'ADM3'
  LEFT JOIN locations t4 ON t4.admin4 = t0.admin4 AND t4.feature_code = 'ADM4'
  GROUP BY t0.name,
           t4.name,
           t3.name, 
           t1.name
  ORDER BY t0.name
```

I get the following results:

```
MIN(t0.row_num)   |   id       |     name    |   town_admin4   |   county_admin3   |  admin1  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       1          |   2652355  |   Cornwall  |                 |                   |  England
```

As you can see the above is incorrect. Row 1 should be record with id 11609029

Why is it behaving like this - why is the MIN operator not working as expected?

Comment: Id is not part of GROUP BY and is not wrapped with aggregate function. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33629201/5070879 - "The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate"

Comment: @LukaszSzozda i've deliberatley excluded id from group by otherwise I will end up with two rows since ids are unique

Comment: In almost every other RDMS you will get an error. It is MySQL specific and as I quoted the result is "indeterminate" in such scenario

Comment: @adam78 . . . This just doesn't look like a useful approach for a reasonable query.  Perhaps you should ask a *new* question, provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've asked the question but no one seems to have been able to provide a detailed answer so I'm trying to break it down into smaller questions and work it out myself. See post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54960930/mysql-conditional-min-max-to-return-distinct-record

Comment: @adam78 : I posted an answer to your other question which I think my answer your (updated) requirements. I think that you should delete this one and stick to the other one.